# pip installation of packages issue

Tags: python, pip

when i tried to install "`transpositionEncrypt`" through pip it said it can't find the releveant version , hence i typed in the command `pip install --upgrade pip` , but it showed the message like below:

```
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/28/91f26bd088ce8e22169032100d4260614fc3da435025ff389ef1d396a433/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
    100% |UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU| 1.5MB 948kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.1
    Uninstalling pip-18.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.1
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\ramadasr\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-uninstall-2qr0q6\\python27amd64\\scripts\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

and then i typed `pip install --upgrade pip --user` for this it is showing like below:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27amd64\lib\site-packages (20.2.4)
```

and now when i type `pip install transpositionDecrypt` again same error is coming ...can any body please guide me how to install this package? **And why this `DEPRECATION:` message coming even though i have python 3.7?**

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement transpositionDecrypt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for transpositionDecrypt
```

Comment: Did you try it with `pip3` . I think your `pip` is defaulted to python2.

Comment: Are you sure `transpositionEncrypt` is an actual installable pip module?

Comment: You are most likely using the wrong `pip` script. You should never call the `pip` scripts (`pip3`, etc.) directly. Instead you should always call the _pip_ module for a specific Python interpreter explicitly such as `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...`. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/